# Swift 2.3 - Decode Emoji String

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8

I am trying to decode an emoji string saved in the `SQL database` as `Amazing \ud83d\udc4c`.
I encode the emoji string with `UTF8 String` and then save it to the `SQL database`.
However, when I try to decode the `UTF 8 String`, it always crash.

It crashed on the line when I try to convert the `string` using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.
If I try to `print` the string, it prints out a lot of garbage data which I am not able to understand, but it does not include the string.

**Code I have tried for decode**:

```
let commentString: String = commentArr[indexPath.row].valueForKey("comment") as! String 
let emojiData = commentString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let emojiString = String(data: emojiData, encoding: NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)
```

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: And if that does not work, please provide a concrete example of input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: @MartinR I'm going to hammer with your suggestion.  If the issue is different, the OP can ping me and I'll reopen the question.